# Cannot insert data to database using Tkinter radio buttons

Tags: python, mysql, database, tkinter

I am using the following code to insert data on the click of a radio button to my database:

```py
import tkinter as tk

Lbl = tk.Label(rwin,text='Gender',bg=lcol,fg='white',font=('system',17,'bold'))
Lbl.place(x=0,y=400)

r = StringVar()

def clicked(value):
    print(r.get())
    query = 'INSERT INTO inventory_db.user (gender) VALUE (%s)'
    conn.execute(query,r.get())
    db.commit()
    conn.close()
    return

radio_b1 = Radiobutton(rwin, text='Male', variable=r, value='Male', command= lambda: clicked(r.get()))
radio_b2 = Radiobutton(rwin, text='Female', variable=r, value='Female', command= lambda: clicked(r.get()))
radio_b1.place(x=0,y=450)
radio_b2.place(x=200,y=450)
```

The `conn` and `db` objects here are for handling connections with my database.

The above code is not working as intended and the data is not inserted when the `radiobutton` is clicked.

Comment: from reading your question, its not clear at first glance what problem you are facing, I would suggest you to edit and add some more information, so that future viewers can understand the problem better and relate it with their own. Thanks

Comment: The problem is mentioned in the title, but it will be better if its also mentioned in the actual question, instead of just code. Perhaps you can explain in more depth of the problem you have been facing.

Comment: Also I would suggest you provide more information about the exact error(if any with its traceback) that you might be facing and also some information about the database where the information will be stored since in one of the question's answers' comments you mentioned that it was now SQL that was giving an error so a database summary might be handy.

Answer (score 0):

You're not formatting the query properly and beware of sql injection.

```
Lbl = tk.Label(rwin,text='Gender',bg=lcol,fg='white',font=('system',17,'bold')).place(x=0,y=400)

r = StringVar()

def clicked(value):
    print(r.get())
    query = 'INSERT INTO inventory_db.user (gender) VALUE (?)'
    conn.execute(query, (r.get(),)) # Extra comma to make it a tuple with one element
    db.commit()
    conn.close()

Radiobutton(rwin, text='Male', variable=r, value='Male', command= lambda: clicked(r.get())).place(x=0,y=450)
Radiobutton(rwin, text='Female', variable=r, value='Female', command= lambda: clicked(r.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

First why don't you use the `value` argument of `clicked()` instead of `r.get()` because you have already passed `r.get()` when executing `clicked()` inside those lambdas.

Also the second argument of `curosr.execute()` should be a tuple or list:

```py
def clicked(value):
    print(value)
    query = 'INSERT INTO inventory_db.user (gender) VALUE (%s)'
    conn.execute(query, (value,)) # use tuple
    db.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: yeah now the error changes to MySQL requiring all elements to be present in order for it to save it raises, that all parameters must be present, is there a way i can only save one element in that user table eg if i press radio button male it saves male to the database column gender individually???

Comment: @Ben99 The SQL requires only one argument.  I don't understand why you get such error.

Comment: @Ben99 May be your table has other fields with *NOT NULL* constraints.